# how can i display products selection on top of product list in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to display products between range of 5000 to 10000 on top in my category page, how can i do this in magento?

I tried to merge collection using

```
$_productCollection1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                            ->getCollection()
                             ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                               ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                              ->addAttributeToFilter('showontop', 1)
                               ->setOrder('price','asc')
                            ->load();

$_productCollection2 = array();
$_productCollection2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                            ->getCollection()
                             ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                               ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                              ->addAttributeToFilter('showontop', 0)
                               ->setOrder('price','desc')
                            ->load();
//print_r($_productCollection1->getAllIds());
print_r($_productCollection2->getAllIds()); die();
$merged_ids = array_merge($_productCollection1->getAllIds(), $_productCollection2->getAllIds());

$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $merged_ids))
->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

but no result

Comment: what u mean by `range of 5000 to 10000`?

Comment: products price between these range and all products between this range have attribute showontop as yes.

Answer (score 1):

u can achieved result by single collection instead of three collection

try this

```
$_productCollection1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                    ->addAttributeToFilter(
                        array('showontop', 'showontop'),
                        array(
                            array('eq'=> 1 ), 
                            array('eq'=> 0 )
                        )
                    )
                    ->addAttributeToSort('price','asc');
```

Comment: u can alos set limit `$_productCollection1->setPage(5000,10000)`

Answer (score 1):

you can price limit by following code

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
         ->addAttributeToSelect('price')->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
         ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $merged_ids));

         $products->addPriceData();

// Apply price limit
$products->getSelect()->where('price_index.final_price <= ?', 10000)
->where('price_index.final_price >= ?', 5000);
      echo '<pre>';   print_r($products->getData());
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code work for me for getting products whose price between 5000 to 10000

Hope it will help you

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection
    ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
    ->addMinimalPrice()
    ->addFinalPrice();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('price',array('from'=>5000,'to'=>10000));
```